# Onsubmit Event do form validation in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a HTML/PHP form that needs validation of each of the entered fields before updating MySQL database. It would be nice if this cold be done as each field is entered...however, I could use the form's action attribute to run a different validation script but then if there are errors I would need to return to the form and re-populate it with previously entered data for correction - not sure how I would do all this but I guess it's possible. However, I've seen a post here that shows how this can be done with a javascript function for the validation but is this possible to do in PHP?  I'm just learning PHP so I'd hate to now have to also learn javascript :(  Some guidance appreciated.

```
    <?php
  if(isset($_POST)) {
      echo __LINE__ . " Form has been posted <br>";
      echo __LINE__ . $_POST['state_city'];
     }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<table border="0" align="center">
    <tr height="29px" width = "220px">
        <td>
            <label for="student_id"><b>Student-ID</b></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Student ID" name="studentid" value="<?php echo $row['studentid'];?>" required>
        </td>
  </tr>

    <tr height="29px" width = "220px">
        <td>
            <label for="student_name"><b>Student name</b></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Student name" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['$studentname'];?>" required>
        </td>
   </tr>

<tr height="29px" width = "220px"><td><label for="start_date"><b>Start Date</b></label></td>
 <td><input type="date" placeholder="Enter start date" name="start_date" value="<?php echo $row['startdate'];;?>" required></td>
</tr>


    <tr height="29px"><td width = "220px">
        <b>Student Grade</b></td>
        <td>
            <select name="sgrade" id="sgrade">
                <option value="1" <?php if ($row['$sgrade'] == '1') echo "selected"; ?>>Grade 1<option>
                <option value="2" <?php if ($row['$sgrade'] == '2') echo "selected"; ?>>Grade 2<option>
                <option value="3" <?php if ($row['$sgrade'] == '3') echo "selected"; ?>>Grade 3<option>
                <option value="4" <?php if ($row['$sgrade'] == '4') echo "selected"; ?>>Grade 4<option>
            </select>
        </td>
    <tr>

    // value?
    <tr height="29px"><td width = "220px"><b>Country of Birth</b></td>
        <td>
            <select name="country" id="country">
            <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            ?>
          
            <?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";

                }
            ?>
            </select>
            <?php
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            mysqli_close($con);
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

<tr height="29px" width = "220px">
    <td><label for="state_city"><b>State and/or main city</b></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Student State and/or Main City" name="state_city" value="<?php echo $row['$state_city'];?>" required></td>
</tr>

<tr height="29px" width = "220px">
        <td><label for="healthcheck"><b>Checked?</b></label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" id="checkyes" name="check" value="1" <?php if ($row['check']) echo "checked";?>>
                <label for="checkyes"> Yes</label><br>
                <input type="radio" id="checkno" name="check" value="0" <?php if (!$row['check']) echo "checked";?>>
                <label for="checkno"> No</label><br><br>
            </td>
        </tr>

</table>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="history.back()" value="Go back!" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
function check() {
  document.getElementById("checkyes").checked = true;
}
function uncheck() {
  document.getElementById(hcheckyes").checked = false;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JavaScript is ideal for validating form fields.

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to be dynamic as the user enters the information you will have to use JavaScript as that would be a front-end solution. With PHP you can do you validation/sanitizing of the data on the server-side as the form is submitted. It is suggested you do both.

For your question of repopulating  this is one way
`<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'] ?? '', ENT_QUOTES); ?>">`

For more info : [click here](https://radu.link/keep-form-data-submit-refresh-php/)

Comment: Thanks @SparKot for your reply but I'm just not ready for javascript, just learning PHP

Comment: Your outline sounds just perfect @AceWright39...not sure how you would do it though but as I mentioned I'm just not ready for javascript, I'm just learning PH so wondering how to do it if at all possible with PHP.

Comment: Well I would suggest you try to learn just a little bit to get the basics for form validation it will help you later on. As for on PHP side that all depends on the data without examples we really can't help https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-javascript-form-validation-by-making-a-form/

Comment: Yes I do intend to move onto javascript @AceWright39 but for this first project I think it's best that I stick with what I know and it ain't much :(  I've just tried  if(isset($_POST)) {..... on the form/PHP script page and see I can validate the data on the same page but unfortunately the form fields are cleared after submit so just seeing how to overcome that.

Comment: Can you add what you have so far? It really hard to suggest anything without seeing at least a small part of what your working with.

Comment: I've edited my post @AceWright39 and added the code that I'm currently working on. All fields are required and each requires validation for different checks.  There are more fields to be added but at this stage I'm simply trying different types of form inputs (dates, check boxes, radio.